# split image horizontally into two unequal parts?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like to use ImageMagick to split it horizontally into two unequal parts of 40-60% (L-R). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as follows in ImageMagick 6. Read the image into MPR memory and delete the original. Then use the MPR copy to crop 40% once with gravity west and crop 60% again with gravity east (that is 40% from the left side and then 60% from the right side). Write those images and then exit with no output, i.e., null:

Unix Syntax:

```
convert red_rect.png +repage -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -gravity west -crop 40x100%+0+0 +repage +write left.png \) \
\( mpr:img -gravity east -crop 60x100%+0+0 +repage +write right.png \) \
null:
```

For Windows,

```
convert red_rect.png +repage -write mpr:img +delete ^
( mpr:img -gravity west -crop 40x100%+0+0 +repage +write left.png ) ^
( mpr:img -gravity east -crop 60x100%+0+0 +repage +write right.png ) ^
null:
```

(In .bat file, double the % to %%)

(For ImageMagick 7, change convert to magick)

Left:

[image]

Right:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a slightly different version:

- load image
- make clone, crop left side and save, delete clone
- revert to original, crop right side and save

---

```
magick GhLiu.png +repage \( +clone -crop 40x100%+0+0 +repage +write left.png +delete \) -gravity east -crop 60x100%+0+0 +repage right.png
```

Comment: Does this work for linux? what is magick? i have no such command

Comment: `magick` is version 7. If you have v6, use `convert` in place of `magick`.

Comment: OK, my Fedora 34 has 6.9. Thanks!